# AndroidPlot Configurator, Define Multiple Arguments in XML

Tags: androidplot

Is it possible to pass multiple arguments into a function through XML configuration, for example setting domainStep or rangeStep through XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of domainStep and rangeStep, these are convenience methods that combine calls to multiple setters into one. TO set domainStep for example, you would set the two associated params domainStepMode and domainStepValue individually in your XML.  This pattern should hold true for any other setter methods that take 2+ params.

Comment: Yeah, is XML the recommended way to do it? It seems quite limited, is there a replacement in the works? Also is 0.62 reasonably stable and/or ready for production?

Comment: 0.62 is pretty stable and will be released soon.  XML is the suggested way to configure anything that you want to supply screen/layout specific params for.  If these settings are going to be used regardless of orientation/screen density then programmatic configuration is fine.  The latest version of  Androidplot supports both "configurator" XML attributes and styleable attributes. Currently the number of styleable attributes is very limited so sticking with configurator for now would be my suggestion.